# Which sketch-to-3D-model software is available?

Tags: 3d, models

I picture this: I paint a 3dmodel from the front, side and top - more or less to scale.

Then I take a photo of it and give it to the software. The software then tries to figure out which part of it fits to which part on the other and after some guidance of me I have a maybe even textured 3D model in front of me.

For teddies there are good software pieces available but I am talking sceneries like surroundings(nature) or inside of buildings.

Comment: That's any 3D modeling software, except it's more than "some guidance" it's a lot of guidance.

Comment: I left an answer but this is off-topic for a game dev site.

Comment: @jhocking The sceneries will be used for gaming actually.

Comment: @Byte56 Yes that's the difference I am talking about. The detection process should be automatic for the user to correct just a few things being wrong.

Comment: Just because something will be used in a game doesn't make it automatically on-topic. For example, pretty much all games include written text; does that mean grammar questions are on-topic? The criteria is "is this question unique to game development?" not "will this be used in a game in any capacity whatsoever?"

Comment: Because something will be used in a game does make it on-topic. But as my reply to your answer already states, you did not understand my question at all so you cannot even judge whether it's fitting.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a bunch of "photo to 3d model" tools available:

[inisght3D](http://insight3d.sourceforge.net/)

[3dsom](http://www.3dsom.com/features/index.html)

[Photosculpt](http://www.photosculpt.net/)

[Photo to 3D](http://www.photo-to-3d.com/)

[Strata Foto 3D](http://www.strata.com/products/strata_3d_cx_suite/strata_foto_3d_cx/)

Note that the first is open source, and the level of quality varies and depends a lot on your source photos. More specifically, none of these will do exactly what you're asking, but these are the closest things because what you're asking is impossible.

Comment: It's important to note that those programs will not work as they require rotation around a few degrees. Rotation in sketches showing top front and left have a natural rotation of 90° which will render such software clueless. Also it is a hand-drawn sketch so proportions can vary slightly.